# How to attach jQuery countdown to code and make it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to web development so please forgive for any shortcomings.

I have been working on a website for a project for a while now and now I have to add a specific countdown on it([Keith Wood Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)) the "Pad with zeroes:" one.

The problem is that, I do not know how to set the target date on it to countdown to and how to attach it to a particular div. 
I have searched the Internet and there are similar questions on stackoverflow but they are for an older version of this countdown. And nowhere is there any answer for how to attach it to a div.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html class="html">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>LMUN - Home</title>

    <meta name="description" content=" Welcome to La Martiniere Model United Nations 2015">
    <meta name="keywords" content="lmun,lucknow mun,la martiniere mun,la martiniere college,la martiniere model un,la martiniere model united nations,lmun 2015">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Slideshow *Starts* -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine0/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine0/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Slideshow *Ends* -->
</head>

<body>

    <div class="brdr_top"></div> <!-- A little gold border at the top -->

    <div  class="header" id="banner"> 
            <img src="images/Website_bannertxtcombo.png" id="banner_txtcombo"/> <!-- The LMUN text image -->
            <img src="images/Logo_Blue_Small.png" id="banner_logo"/> <!-- The LMUN Logo -->
    </div>

    <div class="header" id="navbar"> <!-- The navigation bar and contents *begins* -->

        <div class="nb_item"><span id="space"></span>HOME<span id="space"></span></div>

        <div class="nb_item">ABOUT US <span id="dArrow"></span>
            <ul id="abtus_menu">
                <li class="nb_item_li"><a href="http://www.lamartinierelucknow.org/" target="_blank"><span id="space2"></span>LA MARTINIERE COLLEGE</a></li>
                <li class="nb_item_li"><span id="space2"></span>LMUN 2015</li>
                <li class="nb_item_li"><span id="space2"></span>SECRETARIAT</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <div class="nb_item"><span id="space"></span>REGISTER <span id="dArrow"></span>
        <ul id="rgstr_menu">
            <li class="nb_item_li"><span id="space2"></span>INDIVIDUAL</li>
            <li class="nb_item_li"><span id="space2"></span>DELEGATION</li> 
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="nb_item"><span id="space"></span>COMMITTEES <span id="dArrow"></span>
        <ul id="comt_menu">
            <li class="nb_item_li"><span id="space2"></span>African Union</li>
            <li class="nb_item_li"><span id="space2"></span>Arab League</li>
            <li class="nb_item_li"><span id="space2"></span>SPECPOL</li>
            <li class="nb_item_li"><span id="space2"></span>CCPCJ</li>
            <li class="nb_item_li"><span id="space2"></span>UNSC</li>
            <li class="nb_item_li"><span id="space2"></span>Ad - Hoc</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="nb_item"><span id="space"></span>RESOURCES <span id="space"></span></div>

    <div class="nb_item">EVENTS <span id="dArrow"></span>
        <ul id="evnt_menu">
            <li class="nb_item_li"><span id="space2"></span>KEYNOTE SPEAKERS</li>
            <li class="nb_item_li"><span id="space2"></span>SOCIALS</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="nb_item"><span id="space"></span>SPONSORS</div>

    <div class="nb_item"><span id="space"></span>CONTACT US<span id="space"></span></div>
 </div>
<div id="slideshow">
<!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section --> <!-- add to the <body> of your             page -->
<div id="wowslider-container0">
<div class="ws_images"><ul>
    <li><img src="data0/images/ff.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows0_0"/></li>
    <li><a href="http://wowslider.com"><img src="data0/images/dsc_0160001.jpg" alt="jquery content slider" title="" id="wows0_1"/></a></li>
    <li><img src="data0/images/la_martiniere_college_building,_lucknow.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows0_2"/></li>
</ul></div>
<div class="ws_bullets"><div>
    <a href="#" title=""><span><img src="data0/tooltips/ff.jpg" alt=""/>1</span></a>
    <a href="#" title=""><span><img src="data0/tooltips/dsc_0160001.jpg" alt=""/>2</span></a>
    <a href="#" title=""><span><img src="data0/tooltips/la_martiniere_college_building,_lucknow.jpg" alt=""/>3</span></a>
</div></div><div class="ws_script" style="position:absolute;left:-99%"><a      href="http://wowslider.com">image carousel</a> by WOWSlider.com v8.2</div>
<div class="ws_shadow"></div>
</div>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine0/wowslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine0/script.js"></script>
<!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
</div>

<div id="countdown"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I want to add the countdown to the `countdown` div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`padZeros` is now `padZeroes`. I've inserted variable names for the year, month and day that the countdown approaches. You attach to the target `<div>` by calling `$("#yourDivId").countdown()` with the appropriate options.

```js
$(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var numYears = 0;
  var month = 6;
  var day = 28;
  date = new Date(date.getFullYear() + numYears, month - 1, day);
  $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
    until: date,
    padZeroes: true
  });
  $('#year').text(date.toLocaleDateString());
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <title>jQuery Countdown</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://keith-wood.name/css/jquery.countdown.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    body > iframe {
      display: none;
    }
    #defaultCountdown {
      width: 240px;
      height: 45px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
  <script src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var numYears = 0;
    var month = 6;
    var day = 28;
    date = new Date(date.getFullYear() + numYears, month - 1, day);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
      until: date,
      padZeroes: true
    });
    $('#year').text(date.toLocaleDateString());
  });
</script>

<body>
  <h1>jQuery Countdown Basics</h1>
  Counting down to:
  <div id="year"></div>
  <div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can put it between `<script></script>` tags in your html, just before the closing `<body>` tag (see the updated code above), or you can put it in its own file and include it like       `<script src="myCountdownScript.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

```
<script>

  $(function() {
    var mydate = new Date(); 
    mydate = new Date(mydate .getFullYear() + 1, 11 - 1, 6); 
    $('#countdown').countdown({until: mydate }); 
  ]);

</script>
```

Add this code right before your closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: This variable is no longer available in the new version. Do you want me to post the code here somehow as a link or something?

Comment: What variable? `newYear`?  That's the only variable in the code.  You would replace that with your own date.  Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: The latest version doesn't have this. Do you want me to link the code somehow so you can see?

Comment: @4127157 `newYear` doesn't get created by jquery. He wrote it as an example variable, for you to paste in your own code and modify. Unless you meant the `countdown` function isn't there?

Comment: So how do I attach this to my code to make it usable? I want it to countdown to 6th November 2015. And how do I display this on my webpage in the div? I only know HTML and CSS.